# Numpy table - advanced multiple criteria selection

Tags: python, numpy, selection

I have a table that goes something like this:

```
IDs    Timestamp     Values

124    300.6          1.23
124    350.1         -2.4
309    300.6          10.3
12     123.4          9.00
18     350.1          2.11
309    350.1          8.3

       ...
```

and I'd like to select all the rows that belong to a group of IDs. I know that I can do something like

```
table[table.IDs == 124]
```

to select all of one ID's row, and I could do

```
table[(table.IDs == 124) | (table.IDs == 309)]
```

to get two IDs' rows. But imagine I have ~100,000 rows with over 1,000 unique IDs (which are distinct from row indices), and I want to select all the rows that match a set of 10 IDs.
Intuitively I'd like to do this:

```
# id_list: a list of 10 IDs
table[ table.IDs in id_list ]
```

but Python rejects this syntax. The only way I can think of is to do the following:

```
table[ (table.IDs == id_list[0]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[1]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[2]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[3]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[4]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[5]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[6]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[7]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[8]) |
       (table.IDs == id_list[9]) ]
```

which seems very inelegant to me - too much code and no flexibility for different lengths of lists.
Is there a way around my problem, such as using list comprehensions, or the .any() function?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
subset = table[np.array([i in id_list for i in table.IDs])]
```

If you have a more recent version of numpy, you can use the `in1d` function to make it a bit more compact:

```
subset = table[np.in1d(table.IDs, id_list)]
```

See also this question: [numpy recarray indexing based on intersection with external array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264448/numpy-recarray-indexing-based-on-intersection-with-external-array/5267155#5267155)

Comment: @Comrade42: You're welcome! You can always mark the question as 'answered' for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will probably profile faster than any python `for` loop.  However, I don't think it will do better than `in1d`.  Use it only if you can afford a temporary 2D integer array of `ids.size` by `table.IDs.size`.  Here, `ids` is the numpy array of `id_list`.

```
result = table[~np.all(table.IDs[None]-ids[None].T, 0)]
```